# more margin before block

Tags: beamer, lists, environments, indentation

I have the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}

%\usepackage{colordef}     % local package?
%\usepackage{beamerdefs}   % local package?
%\usepackage{lvblisting}   % local package?

\begin{document}
\frame{
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{itemize}
\item mtest
\item test test test test 

\begin{block}{Methods}
\item the variance/covariance
\item historical simulation
\item \fcolorbox{red}{white}{Monte Carlo simulation}
\end{block}
\end{itemize}    % missing line
}
\end{document}
```

The problem is that the `block` part has the wrong indentation, so it is too much on the left and not on the same line as the text before, how can I change this? I tried `\hspace` but it does not work.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) This is a lot of code. In order to help people who'll help you, could you please remove everything from the code that's _not_ related to your problem? This will turn your document into a so-called [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), which people can copy and compile to reproduce your problem. Otherwise, your question might be in danger of being closed as _too localized_.

Comment: @doncherry ok, now it is ok. any answer?

Comment: @StudentMacor the example you have posted does not compile. `colordef`, `beamerdefs` and `lvblisting` look like custom packages. They may contain the definiton of `block` environment, which is needed. Also the `itemize` list does not have a `end` specified.

Comment: @StudentMacor My mistake `block` is defined by `beamer` (which I haven't used). Adding `\end{itemize}` just before the frame ends and removing custom packages, will make the example work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want the same indentation for block items than for those before the block: Use two separate `itemize` environments and put the second one inside the `block` environment.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\frame{
\frametitle{Test}
\begin{itemize}
\item mtest
\item test test test test 
\end{itemize}

\begin{block}{Methods}
\begin{itemize}
\item the variance/covariance
\item historical simulation
\item \fcolorbox{red}{white}{Monte Carlo simulation}
\end{itemize}
\end{block}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]